# phing loadfile to property does not override previous value

Tags: phing

```
<loadfile property="test-from-file" file="value.txt" />
<echo message="test-from-file = ${test-from-file}" />
<loadfile property="test-from-file" file="value2.txt" />
<echo message="test-from-file = ${test-from-file}" />
```

The second loadfile does not change the value of the test-from-file property.

Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: Well, answering your question: it works as expected. 

Properties are not variables. Properties tend to be immutable, once their value is set they are not expected to change.

There  surely other ways to achieve your target. Can you give the complete context of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments by Jawi, properties are not overridden by design. A property works as a constant in Phing. So if it is already defined, then it won't be changed by later property definitions.

I think that you should revert your `<property>` task call in order to define your preferred sources first.

Alternatively, you can also use `<property override="true">` to alter default behavior and override existing values, changing properties from constant to variable.